# What are drawbacks of serializing custom objects along with their definition?

Tags: python, serialization, pickle, dill

My question is what future repercussions are conceivable when I "force" Python class/function definitions to be serialized along with the objects, by "re-declaring" them in `__main__` just before serialization.

**Details**

It is a common gotcha that Python libraries such as pickle and dill do not serialize class or function definitions along with the objects, if the definitions are not located in `__main__`.

As a result, when deserializing an object, its dependencies must be found in the same location as during serialization. This adds some overhead/inflexibility to deployment, as the definitions must be maintained in a separate package which must be versioned and present in the (production) environment.

I sometimes use the workaround of "mainifying" objects before serializing them, as described for instance by Oege Dijk [here](https://oegedijk.github.io/blog/pickle/dill/python/2020/11/10/serializing-dill-references.html). It essentially redeclares the object's definition in `__main__` so that it will be serialized. The code I use is listed below.

So far this approach has worked well for all my (machine learning) workflows, for quite a while. Yet, it seems quite hacky, and I wonder whether it might cause problems down the line, and which. Of course, the ability to easily modify the serialized definitions is removed (e.g. bugfix). But that is something I can live with. Are there other dangers I am unaware of?

```
import inspect
import types

def mainify(obj):
   
    if obj.__module__ != '__main__':                                                
        
        import __main__       
        is_func = True if isinstance(obj, types.FunctionType) else False                                                            
                                
        # Get source code and compile
        source = inspect.getsource(obj if is_func else obj.__class__)
        compiled = compile(source, '<string>', 'exec')                    

        # "Declare" in __main__ and keep track which key
        # of __main__ dict is new 
        pre = list(__main__.__dict__.keys()) 
        exec(compiled, __main__.__dict__)
        post = list(__main__.__dict__.keys())                        
        new_in_main = list(set(post) - set(pre))[0]
        
        # for function return mainified version, else assign new
        # class to obj and return object
        if is_func:
            obj = __main__.__dict__[new_in_main]            
        else:            
            obj.__class__ = __main__.__dict__[new_in_main]
                
    return obj
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are pickling objects from a single module, you can monkey patch `dill` by assigning this to the variable `dill._dill._main_module` to trick `dill` into thinking *this* module is the `__main__` module. That was an option in previous versions, but was removed, so I don't now if it would work flawlessly. (Maybe you'll need to set `module.__name__` to `"__main__"` or `None` too.)

In the next `dill` release, which should come out in the following days, you'll be able to pickle a whole module (or a subset of its namespace) and load it in a different session, by updating the state of the same module there, if it is installed, or loading its namespace as a dictionary.